# Search Bar is not filtering the result in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is the text input code...

This is code is in SearchForm.js

```
const SearchForm = ({ params, onParamChange }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>Description</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChange={onParamChange}
          value={params.description}
          style={styles.input}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>Location</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChange={onParamChange}
          value={params.location}
          style={styles.input}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

This code is in App.js

I am calling the Github job api  in useFetchJobs

```
const { jobs, loading, error, hasNextPage } = useFetchJobs(params, page);
const [params, setParams] = useState({});
function handleParamChange(e) {
    const param = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setPage(1);
    setParams((prevParams) => {
      return { ...prevParams, [param]: value };
    });
  }
<SearchForm params={params} onParamChange={handleParamChange} />
```

Can you Please tell me why it is not working

Comment: You do not have name attribute on <TextInput ...> whereas while setting state you are setting on target name i.e  [param]: value.

Comment: Another way would be onChange={ (e) => onParamChange('description', e)} and change your method definition to function handleParamChange(param, e) {...}

Comment: Can you tell me what would be the function definition as i have changed but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Changed method and the way onChange is used. Try it out once.

```
<View>
            <Text>Description</Text>
            <TextInput
              onChange={(e) => onParamChange('description', e)}
              value={params.description}
              style={styles.input}
            />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>Location</Text>
            <TextInput
              onChange={(e) => onParamChange('location', e)}
              value={params.location}
              style={styles.input}
            />
          </View>

    function handleParamChange(param, e) {
        
        const value = e.target.value;
        setPage(1);
        setParams((prevParams) => {
          return { ...prevParams, [param]: value };
        });
      }
```

Comment: It will give the Error.. Identifier 'param' has been already declared

Comment: Ohh sorry, My bad I forgot to remove that line. Will update it.

Comment: It still not filtering out the result

Comment: The question is regarding the search bar that it is not working. Not regarding filtering the result. And you have not posted any code for filtering.

Comment: That was the code for filtering out...working in React but it's not working in react native